# Reduction of the diagonalization language to the universal language

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions, undecidability

I'm going through Jeffrey D. Ullman's Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computations. The author reduces an instance of the membership problem in $L_d$ (diagonalization language) to a membership problem in $L_u$. Those are defined as follow:

> $L_d = \{\langle M\rangle \mid \langle M\rangle \notin L(M)\}$
>
> $L_u = \{\langle M, u\rangle \mid u \in L(M)\}$

We start off with assuming $L_u$ is recursive, reduce the problem in $L_d$ to a problem in $L_u$, and solve $L_d$ using the assumption that $L_u$ is recursive, now since $L_d$ is not even recursively enumerable, our assumption that $L_u$ is recursive turns out to be wrong, and since $L_u$ has a TM which accepts it, we conclude $L_u$ is a RE but not recursive language. A few pages later, the books says:

**Theorem 9.7**: If there is a reduction from $P_1$ to $P_2$ then

a) If $P_1$ is undecidable then so is $P_2$

b) If $P_1$ is non  RE then so is $P_2$

I'm confused about the part b) of this theorem, it says reducing a non RE problem to another problem gives you a non RE problem, but having reduced an instance of $L_d$ to an instance of $L_u$, we have reduced a non RE problem to a RE but not recursive problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the proof to show that $L_u$ is not recursive, the autor is using a reduction to $\overline{L_u}$ (which is not RE), not to $L_u$, and explain that a reduction to $L_u$ cannot work since $L_u$ is RE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for helping with the formatting. My professor reduced the problem to $L_u$, I cannot see the problem with doing that, given that we are starting off with the assumption $L_u$ is recursive, it does not matter if we reduce to the complement or to $L_u$ itself, since both would be recursive, the only change we would have is, in the diagram Ullman has constructed, we would have hypothetical algorithm M for $L_u$, and if the hypothetical algorithm accepts, our machine for $L_d$ will reject, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

$L_d$ is general reducible to $L_u$ but not map reducible to $L_u$. To show a language is not decidable, use general reduction is good enough. To show a language is RE or non-RE, you need to apply map reduction. In general reduction, $A\leq \bar{A}, A\leq B \Rightarrow A\leq \bar{B}, etc.$ However, in map reduction, $A\leq_m B \Rightarrow \bar{A}\leq_m \bar{B}$ only. In Jeffrey's book, the above two reductions are not clearly distinguished. His reduction after Theorem 9.7 means map reduction.